# Is there any fail-proof method for getting the dimension of the main window of an Application?

Tags: ios, objective-c

As the title states, is there any fail-proof method for getting the available size for an Application? (Not the actual screen size). Taking in consideration that the App may be on a *Split View*, and that we don't have access to the final App (This is a library without UI)?

Things I've tried:

**AppDelegate Window property**

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.bounds;
```

This will work **only** if the AppDelegate declares the window property, most App do, but there's no guarantee of that.

**Application Key Window**

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.bounds;
```

This will work only if the current `keyWindow` is the main window of the App, but it may be an overlay, or an alert.

**Screen bounds**

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
```

This won't work when the App is displayed on a *Split View*.

**Iterate over all windows**

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows;
//Iterate!
```

Iterate over all available windows, get the one with the larger size, and assume that's the main one. This work on most cases, but sometimes it doesn't for Split View, as there're some windows that won't re-size.

Comment: Looks like the tail wagging the dog.  If you are providing a view then you are told the dimensions of the frame, for example.  In other words, you need to be told, and not have to ask.

Comment: [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width & [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height in case you want to know your device width and height.

Comment: @trojanfoe that may be the case, but I still need to get the info...

Comment: The way you have written the subject of the question is not making sense.

Comment: @Kiran I just changed it, but the body of the question is quite clear..

Comment: Make sure what ever you are going to write does not waste others time. We are here to help but never mind you deserved a down vote here.

Comment: @Kiran My question is a waste of time? Can you explain why?

Comment: Just because it is not making sense according to the wordings.

Comment: @Kiran I see, it is only because of the title. Do you think is good enough now?

Comment: Why do you think you need this information (and get it on your own)?

Comment: @Eiko It's part of the requirements of my current task at work, I can't give too many details about this... But getting this information is quite important. This is a library, and it won't have any UI, so I need to get it by my own. I don't want to end needing to create a View or a Window just for this.

Comment: Well, you maybe should rethink those requirements, then. If your library is not malware, it should be used on purpose. And if it's used on purpose, whoever uses it can easily set the required data. Doing things "magically" is often just not as necessary (and reliable) as one thinks. But of course, you may have other reasons. Then just try your approaches and hope for the best.

Comment: @Eiko Of course it's not a malware, we are just collecting statistics. Thanks for passing by, by the way :)

Comment: You could use delegation. Let the client application (which is using your library) supply this size on demand.

Comment: @Jef Thanks! Yes, that's our last resource...